# Storing the changes made to a branch, merging the branch, then applying the changes to the main branch

Tags: git

So I've gotten myself into a situation.
I have a master branch and out of the master branch, another branch (call it A).

Now, I've finished work in the A branch, made a commit, but then instead of merging it with master, I started working on other features. Before making another commit, I did `git checkout -b B` and then committed the changes to the new B branch. Now what I want to do is somehow detach those changes from the branch A, merge the branch A with master, and then reattach those changes to the master branch (in form of a new branch starting from master).

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: `git cherrypick` your commits

Comment: I'm reading about it but I'm having trouble understanding how it applies to my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the general method for solving this.

First, draw the branch graph (what you have now).

```
...-o-o-o   <-- master
         \
          a-a-a   <-- branchA
               \
                b   <-- branchB
```

where `o` is the original series of commits on `master`, `a` are commits you made on `branchA`, and `b` is the commit (or several commits) you made on `branchB`.

Then, draw what you want to have in the end.  It sounds like you want this, where `M` is a new merge commit on branch `master`, tying in the commits on `branchA`:

```
                  b   <-- branchB
                 /
...-o-o-o-------M     <-- master
         \     /
          a-a-a       <-- branchA
```

To get this, you're going to have to *copy* commit `b`, because once a commit exists it can never be changed, and `b`'s parent is the last `a` commit.  So you'll make a copy of the original `b`.

We really need to call the copy `b'` or something, to distinguish it from the original `b`.  Let's go in and add a mark on the new `b`.  That way we can leave the old `b` in the drawing too.  If I could get SO to color things I could draw the new commits in a different color from the old ones—if you do this on paper or a whiteboard, use some colors here or something.

```
                  b'  <-- new branchB
                 /
...-o-o-o-------M     <-- master
         \     /
          a-a-a       <-- branchA
               \
                b     <-- old branchB, to be deleted when we're done
```

OK, now let's go back to what you have now and compare.  All we need are two new commits, `M` and `b'`.

Making `M` is easy.  Just:

```
git checkout master
git merge branchA
```

If all goes well you now have commit `M`.  (If you have to resolve merge conflicts, do that, and commit, and now you have commit `M`.)  That is, we're up to this point now:

```
...-o-o-o-------M     <-- master
         \     /
          a-a-a       <-- branchA
               \
                b     <-- old branchB, to be deleted when we're done
```

Now we want to copy the original `b` and get the branch label to move.  We can do that with `git cherry-pick` plus some more work, but the command that does the cherry-pick *for* you, *and* moves the label when it's done, is `git rebase`.  We want to check out `branchB` and "rebase" it on to branch `master`:

```
git checkout branchB
git rebase master
```

This will cherry-pick the commits that are on `branchB` and not on `master`, i.e., commit `b`, copying them (or "it", in this case) to a new line of commits coming off (the tip of) `master`.  So this makes `b'` and then makes `branchB` point to `b'`.

If all goes well, you're now all done.  (And it should go just fine in this case.  In more complicated cases you may have to do the same kind of merge-conflict resolving that sometimes have to do with `git merge`—the underlying `cherry-pick`s that rebase does all use the same merge code that `git merge` uses, so that git can automatically do the right thing most of the time.)

Comment: I don't know what to say. This solved my issue completely and without any problems. Awesome work.

Comment: Well, you were (1) lucky in that you had an easy case, and (2) skilled in that you correctly outlined how you got to where you did (i.e., posted a good question :-) ).

Comment: Hi @torek I am in a similar kind of situation. I need changes from a branch which is not merged to master branch(Say branch A). What should be the approach? Should I create a child branch from A and merge master branch to it?

Comment: @Muk: Again, try drawing what you have now (use "A DOG": `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, All Decorate Oneline Graph, A DOG; or use `gitk --all`, or some GUI that shows you the graph). Then decide what you *want* to have, i.e., which commits or copies you want to have available and/or integrated from which branch names, and form a plan to get there from here.